# posting to database needs refresh to show - webmatrix/razor

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

Morning all,

i have created a page to show the contents of my database in input fields, and have set it up so these can be modified and posted back to the database.
What i have done works pretty good, as it does save stuff back to the database, but i need to refresh the page before i can see these changes. I'm thinking i could use jquery to do this maybe, but i need pointing in the right direction. I have currently tried putting the current page as an action href.

Here's the current code i have:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_template1.cshtml";

var db = Database.Open("mydatabase");
var CurrentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
var userdetails = ("SELECT * from UserProfile WHERE UserId='8'");
var quserdetails = db.QuerySingle(userdetails, CurrentUser);

if (IsPost){
var updateuserdetails = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1, TelNumber = @2 WHERE UserID='8'";
db.Execute(updateuserdetails, Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"], Request["TelNumber"]);

  }
  }

  <h1>My Details</h1>
  <hr>
  <form method="post" action="~/Account/MyDetails.cshtml">
  <fieldset>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@quserdetails.FirstName">
  <br>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="LastName" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@quserdetails.LastName">
  <br>
  <label>Telephone Number</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="TelNumber" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@quserdetails.TelNumber">
  <br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cancel</button>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: form can be submitted using jQuery AJAX and use response data from server to manipulate page. Can also load form using AJAX and have server populate it based on url params Need more specifics about what needs to happen once form submitted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but can't you just run this `var quserdetails = db.QuerySingle(userdetails, CurrentUser);` again after you ran the `db.Execute(updateuserdetails, Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"], Request["TelNumber"]);` inside `if(IsPost)` ? Looks like it'll fecth the data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax submit, it would post form using ajax. So page will not get refreshed

download files

1. jquery.ajax.form.js
2. jquery.validate.js

along with jquery.js

```
$('#form1').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            var options = {
                url:$('#form1').attr('action'),
                success:function(response){
                    data = $.parseJSON(response);

                }
            };
            $("form#form1").ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Kautil, but where do it specify what inputs get sent to what database column?

Comment: as you get all data in $_POST in normal submit, same way you will get all form data in $_POST